# Downloading Rails Assets - File-paths In Development vs Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, download, sendfile

I have a `downloads_controller.rb` with a single `download` action which I want to trigger the download of a file that lives in a folder called `downloads` which lives in a folder called `download_assets` which I have added to my asset paths.

```
- download_assets [Added to asset paths]
   - downloads
      - file_1.pdf
      - file_2.pdf
      ...
```

I can successfully access any files in the folder using:

<strike>http://my-app.dev/assets/downloads/file.pdf</strike>

In order to use send_file I need the file system path to this file rather than the URL. I can get the path the the root of my Rails project using `Rails.root`, and the path to the file using `asset_path(path)`. However, the problem is that because I'm in development, there is no file at this path. The file is stored in:

```
path/to/rails/project/app/assets/download_assets/downloads/file.pdf
```

The action:

```
   def download
      @download = Download.find(params[:id])
      file_path = "downloads/#{@download.filename}.pdf"
      file_path = "#{Rails.root}#{ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path(file_path)}"
      send_file(file_path, :type=>"application/pdf", x_sendfile: true)
   end
```

To get this to work in development I need to use the following:

```
"#{Rails.root}/app/assets/download_assets/#{file_path}"
```

However this will fail in Production because assets will be precompiled and moved into `assets`.

My current workaround is:

```
   file_path = "downloads/#{@download.filename}.pdf"
   if Rails.env == "development" || Rails.env == "test"
        file_path = "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/download_assets/#{file_path}"
    else
        file_path = "#{Rails.root}{ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path(file_path)}"
    end
```

**Is there an alternative to supplying a different path based on environment as this seems fragile?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

In `/config/initializers` create a file called say "`config.yml`"  Set it up like so:

**config.yml:**

```
---
## NOT a tab character.  3 spaces.  (In case that affects you)                                                                                                                            
development:
   path_to_uploads: /path/to/downloads/for/development

production:
   path_to_uploads: /path/to/downloads/for/production

test:
   path_to_uploads: /path/to/downloads/for/test
```

Then create a file in the same directory (`/config/initializers/`) called `config.rb`

**config.rb:**

```
APP_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/initializers/config.yml")
```

Hop over to your controller:

**foo_controller.rb:**

```
      class FooController < ApplicationController
           def download
              # ... 
              path_to_uploads = Rails.root.to_s + APP_CONFIG["#{Rails.env}"]['path_to_uploads'] 
## By handing it the Rails.env object, it will return the current environment and handle selecting the correct environment for you.
        end
    end
```

There is an excellent RailsCast on using YAML to find the environment [here.](http://railscasts.com/episodes/85-yaml-configuration-file)

Hope that helps!

---