# Configuring Paths in Development and Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, pdf

I have an app that lets users download itineraries if they like the preview of the first page. In order to make the preview, I use PDF Reader to parse the original document and create a PDF version of the first page.

In development, the original itinerary is stored in the public folder.

```
@itin_preview = itinerary
reader = PDF::Reader.new("public/#{@itin_preview/document_file_name}")
formatted_page = reader.page(1)
formatted_text = formatted_page.text.gsub! /\s+/, ''
page_text = formatted_text.gsub!(/$/, "\n")
```

This return `public/itinerary.pdf`. However, in production, the itinerary is stored on Amazon AWS, so i tried to configure an initializer with different paths in a YAML file for development and production, taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124673/downloading-rails-assets-file-paths-in-development-vs-production).

**config.rb**

```
APP_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/initializers/config.yml")
```

**config.yml**

```
development:
  itinerary_path: /public/#{@itin_preview.document_file_name}
production:
  itinerary_path: <%= asset_path "#{@itin_preview.document_file_name}" %>
```

When I input the constant into my PDF Reader like so,

```
reader = PDF::Reader.new(APP_CONFIG[Rails.env]['itinerary_path'])
```

I get the following error:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 19ms (ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)

ArgumentError (input must be an IO-like object or a filename):
```

I have double checked that `APP_CONFIG[Rails.env]['itinerary_path']` spits out `public/itinerary.pdf` in development. So why does it work as a string but not as a Constant?

How can i get it to work?

Comment: So its its not working in production?

Comment: now `APP_CONFIG[Rails.env]['itinerary_path'] ` doesnt work in development either.